# HttpClient in Universal Windows app running on Windows 10 IOT Core throws Exception from HRESULT: 0x80072EFD

Tags: c#, .net, dotnet-httpclient, win-universal-app, windows-10-iot-core

I´m using VS2015 to deploy a universal app to a Raspberry Pi 2 Model B running Windows 10 IOT Core (10.0.10240). Any usage of the HttpClient to call a WebService or retrieve some data like the following

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
var re = await client.GetAsync("http://somehost/api/values/5");
```

yields an Exception from HRESULT: 0x80072EFD.

Capabilities

- Internet (Client)
- Internet (Client & Server)
- Private Networks (Client & Server)

are set in the app manifest. Any suggestions?

Comment: This hresult is defined as ERROR_INTERNET_CANNOT_CONNECT, so I believe it's not related to your code or the capabilities.

Comment: Thank you, I´m still investigating: disabling the firewall in the raspberry pi didn´t change anything, as well as trying to execute the code without a debugger attached (since debugging is done via network), still searching..

Comment: @Dominik did you tried a local host in your network and not over the internet?

Comment: @Alex-H: Actually so far only a local host on my network, specifically the one i deployed and debugged the pi from. Ping from a powershell session on the pi to the host is returning just fine.

Comment: @Everyone: This is more than emberrasing: After upgrading my dev pc to WIn10, my home network is detected as a public one, leading to the firewall completely locking down my machine from the local network (still wondering why it´s allowing pings to pass), hence the service hosted in IIS was not reachable, adjusting the configuration on the dev pc solved the problem. Eldar & Alex, I owe you a beer or drink of your choice

Answer (score 0):

Experienced the 0x80072efd problem. Appeared to be something with proxy settings gone wrong. The following worked for me (from admin command prompt):

`netsh winhttp reset proxy`