# HttpRequestException when using HttpClient?

Tags: c#, win-universal-app, dotnet-httpclient

I was having a `WebClient` that was requesting an URL. I wanted to do the same thing within a UWP application, and I saw that I had to import `Microsoft.Net.Http` and use `HttpClient`.

So I replaced this(that was in a Class library):

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
client.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.UserAgent] = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/535.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/15.0.874.121 Safari/535.2";
string content = client.DownloadString(url);
```

By this in a PCL library:

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
string content = await client.GetStringAsync(url);
```

And now I got this exception:

```
System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException occurred
  HResult=-2147012867
  Message=An error occurred while sending the request.
  Source=System.Net.Http
  StackTrace:
       at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.<SendAsync>d__1.MoveNext()
    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
       at XXXX.YYYY.MHDJ.ZZZZ.<ParsePage>d__4.MoveNext()
  InnerException: 
       ErrorCode=-2147012867
       HResult=-2147012867
       Message=Le texte associé à ce code d’erreur est introuvable.

Impossible d'établir une connexion avec le serveur

       Source=""
       StackTrace:
            at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
            at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
            at System.Net.Http.HttpHandlerToFilter.<SendAsync>d__1.MoveNext()
         --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
            at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
            at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
            at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.<SendAsync>d__1.MoveNext()
       InnerException:
```

I don't think the issue is the Headers, so what is?

Comment: I had the same error because Charles Proxy was turned on. Closing the app solved the problem

Answer (score 2):

The `HRESULT` code `-2147012867` in hex is `0x80072EFD`. The `0x8007` prefix means it's actually an [`HRESULT` wrapper around a `Win32` error code](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg567305.aspx). The original `Win32` error code is `0x2EFD`.

The [`Win32` error code list](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681384(v=vs.85).aspx) tells us that values `0x2EE0` through `0x2F8F` are `ERROR_INTERNET_*` error codes, which sounds like the right kind of error. After following the link to the [`Win32` `ERROR_INTERNET_*` error code listing](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa385465(v=vs.85).aspx), we can convert our error code `0x2EFD` back to decimal (`12029`) and discover it is error `ERROR_INTERNET_CANNOT_CONNECT`:

> The attempt to connect to the server failed.

Rather generic, and not much help.

I'd recommend trying the connection again, ensuring that your application has appropriate permissions and the device actually has a working Internet connection. If that doesn't work, try adding the `UserAgent` header back in; it's possible that the networking stack on your device insists on it.

**Update:** Tracking down the error code meaning was rather tedious, so I [wrote an app to do it](https://errorcodelookup.com/?q=-2147012867).

Comment: I've added the UserAgent now, and same error, I tried 10 time consecutively and still doesn't work. For the rights, I only added "Internet (Client)", I don't know if there is something else that I should add?

Comment: If the url you are calling is an internal domain, you also need to check the Private Networks capability.

Comment: @J4N: Was the same exact test working with `WebClient`?

Comment: @StephenCleary Yes, the exact code that I pasted work with `WebClient`(With the exact same URL). Also I tried some other URL(like http://google.com or such)

Comment: @MarkW I'm only using web address. but I don't know how it react if there some local proxy(like fiddler) in the middle

Comment: @MarkW Anyway I tried with this additional right and it still doesn't work

Comment: Attach a proxy like fiddler and see if anything is being sent at all.

Answer (score 1):

Experienced the 0x80072efd problem. Has cost me hours if not days to solve. The solution that worked for me was the following command from an admin command prompt:

`netsh winhttp reset proxy`

Answer (score 0):

There are so many ways to do things, and I'm not suggesting that this is the best way, but this is how I construct my methods.  This example is what I use to return a list of U.S. State objects that are provided in JSON format.  One important note... this is in a Universal Windows class library, not a PCL... but I do not believe it uses anything that a PCL does not have access to.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

//IStateInfo is my model class interface
public async Task<IList<IStateInfo>> GetAllStatesAsync()
{
    List<IStateInfo> states = new List<IStateInfo>();
    try
    {
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://YourBaseApiHere");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
            string url = "lookup/usstates";
            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(url);
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var json = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                //deserialize into client class Newtonsoft JSON used here
                var lst = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<StateInfo>>(json);
                states.AddRange(lst);
            }
            else
            {
                //notify of failed web call here
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        //notify of error
    }
    return states;
}
```

Comment: I tried to do exactly the same thing(using base address, using MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue, calling same methods(but with my URI), no luck, still the exact same error, I've the feeling that it's not related directly with the code, but I can't find with what it is related then.

Comment: found someone with same error, but on IOT - ended up being a firewall configuration issue... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32489813/httpclient-in-universal-windows-app-running-on-windows-10-iot-core-throws-except

Comment: I've checked but currently I've no active firewall(even the windows one is disabled). And I've no antivirus too, disabled windows defender. I also just tried to start Visual studio as administrator, no luck :(

Comment: in fact after I tried all this(changing right, starting as admin, making my windows update, updating all nuget packages) it was not working, and now after a restart, it seems to works.... Morality, I should reboot more often :/ Sorry guys